# randomly choose different sets in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, sampling

I am trying to randomly select a set of integers in numpy and am encountering a strange error. If I define a numpy array with two sets of different sizes, `np.random.choice` chooses between them without issue:

```
Set1 = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [2, 4]])
In:  np.random.choice(Set1)
Out: [4, 5]
```

However, once the numpy array are sets of the same size, I get a value error:

```
Set2 = np.array([[1, 3, 5], [2, 4, 6]])
In:   np.random.choice(Set2)
ValueError: a must be 1-dimensional
```

Could be user error, but I've checked several times and the only difference is the size of the sets. I realize I can do something like:

```
Chosen = np.random.choice(N, k)
Selection = Set[Chosen]
```

Where `N` is the number of sets and `k` is the number of samples, but I'm just wondering if there was a better way and specifically what I am doing wrong to raise a value error when the sets are the same size.

Printout of `Set1` and `Set2` for reference:

```
In: Set1
Out: array([list([1, 3, 5]), list([2, 4])], dtype=object)
In: type(Set1)
Out: numpy.ndarray

In: Set2
Out: 
array([[1, 3, 5],
       [2, 4, 6]])
In: type(Set2)
Out: numpy.ndarray
```

Comment: Have you actually printed the array? The dtype is different. Numpy doesn't actually support ragged arrays, so your first array is not what you think.

Comment: oh thanks.  Yeah when i printed the first Set it comes out as an array of two lists whereas  the non-ragged arrays shows the array without the lists.  But both are numpy.ndarrays when i check type.  I'll edit the question to show the print out.

Comment: Type is a python concept, dtype is a numpy concept. Everything that comes out of `np.array` is a `np.ndarray`. But anything with `dtype=object` is not really much of an array. It's really more of a python list that can be modified in content but not in size, and generally slower.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is caused by a misunderstanding of how numpy arrays work. The first example can not "really" be turned into an array because numpy does not support ragged arrays. You end up with an array of object references that points to two python lists. The second example is a proper 2xN numerical array. I can think of two types of solutions here.

The obvious approach (which would work in both cases, by the way), would be to choose the index instead of the sublist. Since you are sampling with replacement, you can just generate the index and use it directly:

```
Set[np.random.randint(N, size=k)]
```

This is the same as

```
Set[np.random.choice(N, k)]
```

If you want to choose without replacement, your best bet is to use [`np.random.choice`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.choice.html), with `replace=False`. This is similar to, but less efficient than shuffling. In either case, you can write a one-liner for the index:

```
Set[np.random.choice(N, k, replace=False)]
```

Or:

```
index = np.arange(Set.shape[0])
np.random.shuffle(index)
Set[index[:k]]
```

The nice thing about [`np.random.shuffle`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.shuffle.html), though, is that you can apply it to `Set` directly, whether it is a one- or many-dimensional array. Shuffling will always happen along the first axis, so you can just take the top `k` elements afterwards:

```
np.random.shuffle(Set)
Set[:k]
```

The shuffling operation works only in-place, so you have to write it out the long way. It's also less efficient for large arrays, since you have to create the entire range up front, no matter how small `k` is.

The other solution is to turn the second example into an array of list objects like the first one. I do not recommend this solution unless the *only* reason you are using numpy is for the `choice` function. In fact I wouldn't recommend it at all, since you can, and probably should, use pythons standard [`random`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html) module at this point. Disclaimers aside, you can coerce the datatype of the second array to be `object`. It will remove any benefits of using numpy, and can't be done directly. Simply setting `dtype=object` will still create a 2D array, but will store references to python `int` objects instead of primitives in it. You have to do something like this:

```
Set = np.zeros(N, dtype=object)
Set[:] = [[1, 2, 3], [2, 4]]
```

You will now get an object essentially equivalent to the one in the first example, and can therefore apply `np.random.choice` directly.

**Note**

I show the legacy [`np.random`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/index.html) methods here because of personal inertia if nothing else. The correct way, as suggested in the documentation I link to, is to use the new [Generator](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generator.html) API. This is especially true for the [`choice`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.Generator.choice.html) method, which is much more efficient in the new implementation. The usage is not any more difficult:

```
Set[np.random.default_rng().choice(N, k, replace=False)]
```

There are additional advantages, like the fact that you can now choose directly, even from a multidimensional array:

```
np.random.default_rng().choice(Set2, k, replace=False)
```

The same goes for [`shuffle`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.Generator.shuffle.html), which, like `choice`, now allows you to select the axis you want to rearrange:

```
np.random.default_rng().shuffle(Set)
Set[:k]
```

Comment: wow this is awesome thanks!  Just wondering is there anyway to do without replacement with np.random.randint?  ...also just curious why does python still return numpy.ndarray for the set of ragged arrays?

Comment: You would expect a constructor to do its best. When `np.array` decides that something can't be turned into an array because the subsequences are ragged, it simply treats the subsequences as object references. That's generally what you want. In fact, you can find a number of questions on SO about why setting `dtype=object` doesn't make an array of lists for non-ragged inputs.

Comment: @phntm. I've updated to show sampling without replacement.

Comment: @phntm. On second thought, you may want to just shuffle your array...

Comment: `numpy.random.choice` with `replace=False` is extremely inefficient, due to generating an entire permutation of the input under the hood. This is a design mistake that could not be corrected due to backward compatibility constraints. The new [Generator API](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generator.html) does not have this problem. If possible, new code should use the Generator API.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica. Thanks for the tip. I haven't dealt with the random machinery enough to have used generators much, so I focused more on the indexing aspect here.

Comment: [`numpy.random.Generator.choice`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.Generator.choice.html#numpy.random.Generator.choice) also natively supports choosing random rows from a 2D array, as well as higher-dimension analogues of this operation and choice along arbitrary axes, through the `axis` argument.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica. I added a note at the bottom. The new API is objectively better for what OP wants in every way. It was worth reading docs for 2 minutes.

Comment: @phntm. Glad it helped. I'm new to the new rng api (but not to numpy as a whole), so it was an interesting thing to look at.